# Is this a bug in inet_pton with IPv6?

Tags: c, ubuntu, ipv6

When trying to resolve Facebook's numeric IP address as a test `2620:0:1cfe:face:b00c::3:`, if I leave the terminating `0` off the address, `inet_pton()` barfs. If I put it back on everything works.

Running ubuntu 9.10:

```
rc = inet_pton(AF_INET6, "2620:0:1cfe:face:b00c::3:0", &ip); -> OK
rc = inet_pton(AF_INET6, "2620:0:1cfe:face:b00c::3:", &ip); -> returns -2
```

`ping6 -n www.v6.facebook.com` returns the IP address w/o the trailing 0.

Answer (score 2):

It seems that ping, in it's great wisdom, adds a colon after the IP address like so:

```
PING maclawran.ca (173.230.128.18) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from ns.maclawran.ca (173.230.128.18): icmp_seq=1 ttl=51 time=50.3 ms
```

Of course if you're pinging an IPv6 address, it's already got lots of colons in it:

```
PING 2620:0:1cfe:face:b00c::3(2620:0:1cfe:face:b00c::3) 56 data bytes
64 bytes from 2620:0:1cfe:face:b00c::3: icmp_seq=1 ttl=52 time=9.44 ms
======================================^ << THANKS PING
```

Comment: "2620:0:1cfe:face:b00c::3:" isn't a valid abbreviation of "2620:0:1cfe:face:b00c::3:0" anyway.

Comment: If this answers your question, please accept it. If this is just additional information, please edit your question and add it. I'm not quite sure which is the case, or I would have done it for you. I've edited both for formatting and general clean up.

Comment: ping's output format is IP-ADDRESS: RESULTS - of course with IPv6 addresses, they already contain lots of colons... so it gets confusing very quickly.  Solution would be for ping to either surround the IPv6 address in square brackets (done for http access), or to put a space after the ip address and before the colon.  Of course, you make this mistake once, you *never* make it again...

Comment: And by turning it into 2620:0:1cfe:face:b00c::3:0 instead of the correct 2620:0:1cfe:face:b00c::3, it's now also a completely different address :)